# After Importing Spatial database to QGIS,How to analyze the data on Google Maps?

Tags: c#, postgresql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, qgis

I have imported Database (Point Feature) to QGIS,able to see the points on Google Earth.

How can I get each point details with any programming language?

Is there any chance to use C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to work with QGIS using C#. QGIS is written on C++, so you can interact with it using C++. Also QGIS supports Python scripts. See this [link](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/getting_started_with_pyqgis.html) for getting started.